# Can I have an if statement change what variable is accessed in a loop

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, optimization

Hey I'm in a situation where I have a for loop that does some stuff and I want to make a line of code either call a function passing in an array indexed by the for loops index, or run a single (not array) variable for every call of that function, I know I could do that by putting an if statement inside the for loop but i'd be repeating the same if statement over and over getting the same result. So is there a way good way I can run the if statement before the for loop and the result of that if statement run the same for loop but that one call passes in the array or the variable?

Code Example

```
        for (int i = 0; i < CurrentVerticalList.Count; i++)
        {
            GuiGeneral CGroup = CurrentVerticalList[i];

            CGroup.ResizeUsingStandard(ForcedResize[i]); //I want the condition before the for 
                                                         //loop to have ForcedResize[i] here if
                                                         //true and another variable here of the
                                                         //same type but not an array if false.

            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                GlobalListIndex[j]++;
            }

            CGroup.MoveElementTo(CCoord, false);

            CCoord.y += CGroup.ElementRect.WidthHeight.y;
        }
```

Comment: `CGroup.ResizeUsingStandard(condition ? ForcedResize[i] : othervar)` ?

Comment: does that not still check the condition every time it loops or does that only check the condition once?

Comment: this might help [Dynamic Array](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/what-are-c-sharp-dynamic-arrays/)

Comment: It does check the condition every time. If the value never changes, capture that value in a `bool` variable before your loop, and use that variable - that's cheap

Comment: What kind of a condition you want to put? Is it random for every element? Is it different for every element of the loop? or is the value of the condition doesn't change until the loop finishes?

Comment: it is the same result for every element in the loop, it is dependent on a bool that is outside of the for loop and not affected by it at all. Thats why I want the condition outside the for loop, so it only runs once and then based on what if that condition is true or false, changes if either the array or variable gets used in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, moving your condition check out of your for loop:

```
Func<int, double> GetResizeFromForcedResize = (index => ForcedResize[index]);
Func<int, double> GetResizeFromVariable  = (index => fixVariable);
var GetResizeValue = condition? GetResizeFromForcedResize : GetResizeFromVariable;

for (int i = 0; i < CurrentVerticalList.Count; i++)
{
    GuiGeneral CGroup = CurrentVerticalList[i];

    CGroup.ResizeUsingStandard(GetResizeValue(i));

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        GlobalListIndex[j]++;
    }

    CGroup.MoveElementTo(CCoord, false);

    CCoord.y += CGroup.ElementRect.WidthHeight.y;
}
```

Edit: Wanted to let you know that the other answers here are still doing a check at every iteration, but not this one.

Comment: This fits perfect for what i wrote, but I tested this against just doing a condition inside the loop and to my surprise doing the condition inside the loop seems faster. I assumed doing the condition once would be faster but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

Eh, hard to understand the question to me but i recon what you want is something along these lines, could've helped with more types supplied, but you could make the intend achievable using a local function:

```
        ForcedResizeArrayType other = new object(); //TODO: Define return type

        bool condition = ResolveCondition();  //TODO: Define condition to be true or false


        ForcedResizeArrayType GetOneOr(int i, bool condition, 
        ForcedResizeArrayType[] forcedResizeArray)
        {
            return condition ? forcedResizeArray[i] : other;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < CurrentVerticalList.Count; i++)
        {
            CGroup.ResizeUsingStandard(GetOneOr(i, condition, ForcedResize));
        }
```

It varies from week to week if i love or hate those local functions, but they have uses